# Spring JPA Postgresql - Composite keys are duplicated when one is not

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, composite-key

I am having some troubles and hope you can help me, I have the following entity:

App class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "apps")
public class App {
    @Id
    @Column(length = 15)
    private String name;

    @Column(length = 40)
    private String web;

    @Column(length = 50)
    private String mailDomain;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "app")
    private List<SocialNetwork> socialNetworks = new ArrayList<>();

//getters, setters, equals and hash
```

Social Network Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "social_networks")
@IdClass(SocialNetworkCompositeKey.class)
public class SocialNetwork {
    @Id
    @Column(length = 15)
    private String name;

    @Id
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "app")
    private App app;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 40)
    private String url;

//getters, setters, equals and hash
```

SocialNetworkCompositeKey Class:

```
public class SocialNetworkCompositeKey implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private String app;

//equals and hash
```

Now whenever I try to insert an App either in my Program or directly in the DB, I get the Exception:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "uk_590itpuvpqppd9f0g2w5y8bml"
  Detail: Key (app)=(Uli App) already exists.
```

This while trying to insert 2 records with:

```
        app       name     url
----+---------+-----------+---------
  1 | Uli App | Twitter   | http...
----+---------+-----------+---------  
  2 | Uli App |  Linkedin | http...
----+---------+-----------+---------
```

I am using the latest version of both Spring boot and JPA. So I use `JpaRepository` for my repositories. Even if I try to enter those rows manually in the DB with pgAdmin it'll give me the same error.

I am not sure if it's related but I use `ddl-auto: update` from hibernate to auto create the tables.

I hope you guys can help me, cheers.

Comment: releation between `App` And `SocialNetwork` is not right.

Comment: What @MortezaJalambadani is trying to say: You have only  @JoinColumn(name = "app") but the SocialNetwork has a composite key so you should have two JoinColumns

Comment: Hi @SimonMartinelli  , putting a JoinColumn for name didn't work and gives the same problem, also name is a field from the social network, not a PK to another table as 'app'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @Morteza said my relationships were wrong. With this and other tutorial I found after digging alot (I really Googled alot before posting this) I was able to fix it by changing the relationship from `@OneToMany` to `@ManyToOne` in the `Social Networks` class. These are changes I've made:

App class:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "app", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<SocialNetwork> socialNetworks = new ArrayList<>();
```

Social Network class:

```
@Id
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private App app;
```

Thanks for the help guys!